# Google sheets, summing over a formula?

Tags: google-sheets

Apologies if this is a little unclear, or this question has been asked already. It's a little difficult to explain, but I've bolded my question - it's essentially about shortening formulas.

I'm running a payment plan waterfall model. My code **works**, but, it's er, you know...

```
IF($K2=Q$1,Assumptions!$E$56*($N2+$O2),IF(AND($K2<Q$1,$M2>Q$1),Assumptions!$E$56*$P2/$L2,0)) + IF(edate($K2,1)=Q$1,Assumptions!$F$56*($N2+$O2),IF(AND(edate($K2,1)<Q$1,edate($M2,1)>Q$1),Assumptions!$F$56*$P2/$L2,0)) +  IF(edate($K2,2)=Q$1,Assumptions!$F$56*($N2+$O2),IF(AND(edate($K2,2)<Q$1,edate($M2,2)>Q$1),Assumptions!$F$56*$P2/$L2,0)) +  IF(edate($K2,3)=Q$1,Assumptions!$F$56*($N2+$O2),IF(AND(edate($K2,3)<Q$1,edate($M2,3)>Q$1),Assumptions!$F$56*$P2/$L2,0)) +  IF(edate($K2,4)=Q$1,Assumptions!$F$56*($N2+$O2),IF(AND(edate($K2,4)<Q$1,edate($M2,4)>Q$1),Assumptions!$F$56*$P2/$L2,0)) +  IF(edate($K2,5)=Q$1,Assumptions!$F$56*($N2+$O2),IF(AND(edate($K2,5)<Q$1,edate($M2,5)>Q$1),Assumptions!$F$56*$P2/$L2,0)) + IF(edate($K2,6)=Q$1,Assumptions!$F$56*($N2+$O2),IF(AND(edate($K2,6)<Q$1,edate($M2,6)>Q$1),Assumptions!$F$56*$P2/$L2,0))
```

...pretty long.

Essentially what's going on is: the assumption is, when we launch a product, we sell say 80% in the first month, and 2.5% every subsequent month until we each 100%.

I'd like the `80%` and the `2.5%` to be variables (listed as `Assumptions!$E$56` and `Assumptions!$E$56`) here.

Obviously a little long. But noticed after the first `IF` clause, the subsequent ones are **actually identical**, the only difference being the number inside `edate(__,2)`, `edate(__,3)`...

So my question is - can this code be tidied up into some sort of for loop? Python would make it pretty simple to increment over the variable `edate(__,i)` and sum over `i = 1:6`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, there is. Usually looping is emulated by `Sequence(N)`, which makes an array of numbers from [1,N] vertically, which is somewhat like your Python range. Then you can do stuff to it as an `ArrayFormula`.

In your case, you end up with two terms: your initial term using $E, and all the looped stuff using $F. I see 6 terms, so I will use `Sequence(6)`:

```
=IF(
    $K2=Q$1,
    Assumptions!$E$56*($N2+$O2),
    IF(
        AND(
            $K2<Q$1,
            $M2>Q$1
        ),
        Assumptions!$E$56*$P2/$L2,
        0
    )
) + ArrayFormula(SUM(
    IF(
        edate($K2,SEQUENCE(6))=Q$1,
        Assumptions!$F$56*($N2+$O2),
        IF(
            (edate($K2,SEQUENCE(6))<Q$1)*
            (edate($M2,SEQUENCE(6))>Q$1),
            Assumptions!$F$56*$P2/$L2,
            0
        )
    )
))
```

And if you want, you can give your Assumption values names using named ranges.

Comment: Wow, this is beautiful. Thank you.
I'm being warned against how these array formulas slow things down, would you have any comments on the performance of them?

Comment: @ChristopherTurnbull Sure. Usually it's not a problem for simple range calculations like this, but sometimes the code can get very complex and unreadable. Look for potentially slow operations or repeated code, and memoize/cache them in another set of cells or sheet, then use a Named Range to reference it. That way, it only does one calculation per formula or set of cells. Sometimes, we can get so obsessed with cramming everything into a single cell and forget that repeated code is bad. If I really wanted to optimize this one, for example, I could have done that with the `SEQUENCE(6)`.

Comment: thanks. your answer is banging. my model now has slick flexibility :D